# Proving and finding the existence of infinite integers $n$ that can be represented as the sum of $k$ squares $1 \leq k \leq (n-14)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Edit: For every $k$ in that interval.

I came across a really, really interesting statement where I want to

> Prove the existence of infinite integers $n$ that can be represented as the sum of $k$ perfect squares $1 \leq k \leq (n-14)$.

I have had a few issues, one of the biggest is the significance of $(n-14)$.
I don't really know how to actually do this, and I really am looking for a creative solution, but I just don't have any ideas, and if I do, there are just some that I don't wanna tackle as they wouldn't be very satisfactory.

It really is about finding a $k$-sphere that has a radius of $n$ that has at least $(n-14)$ integer points where we can take $(n-15)$ of these points to have at least one zero coordinate in a way that the number of zeros is mutually different. I was trying to figure out conditions where we can go from a $k$-sphere to a $(k-1)$-sphere, but I don't really have many ideas. There's also the cheap ideas too, for example, if we have any of these numbers being odd, then we know that adding $3$ dimensions also works, and then if we prove that $(n-14)$ dimensions imply $(n-3)$, then we could easily see that $4n$ also satisfies this condition, but this idea seems, like I said, cheap and not satisfying, but I at least know that some numbers have to repeat.

I am really lost for this one. If anyone has an idea, could you write it as a hint and then write the solution with a spoiler? Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Every positive integer is the sum of $4$ perfect squares. So every $n\geq18$ can be represented as the sum of $k$ perfect squares with $1\leq k\leq(n-14)$. That yields infinitely many integers.

Comment: Do you mean that $n$ can be represented as the sum of $k$ perfect squares for *some* $k$ with $1\leq k\leq(n-14)$, or for *every* $k$ with $1\leq k\leq(n-14)$?

Comment: @Servaes I didn't know that, but that sounds really cool, but yeah, my question is for every k in that interval. I'll edit the question. That might be really useful, though, to try proving it.

Comment: @Servaes Thank you. Also, which one do you mean?

Comment: Because I couldn't find any solution to this, or mention of it.

Comment: Also, when expressing $n$ as a sum of squares, should the squares be nonzero?

Comment: By perfect squares, I meant positive integers squared.

Comment: Also, what is the source of this statement?

Comment: @Servaes A friend showed me this, from a book he had. Sorry, I didn't see your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an observation for the higher values of $k$; for $k=n-14$ note that
$$n=3^2+2^2+2^2+1^2+1^2\ldots+1^2.$$
For $k=n-15$ note that
$$n=4^2+1^2+1^2+\ldots+1^2.$$
For $k=n-16$ note that
$$n=3^2+3^2+1^2+1^2+\ldots+1^2.$$
In each case, writing $m+d$ as the sum of $d$ nonzero perfect squares yields an expression for $n$ as a sum of $k=n-m$ perfect squares. Note that this does not depend on $k$ or $n$, only on $m=n-k$. So for most values of $k$, the condition that $n$ is a sum of $k$ perfect squares does not pose any restriction on $n$ at all.

For lower values of $k$; the case $k=1$ tells you that $n$ is a perfect square, and $k=2$ tells you that $n$ is a sum of two perfect squares, yielding a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of that, since we could always choose a value $c$ for which $(n-c)^2 > n$. Thereby it is easy to see that the sum must involve repeating numbers.

Comment: Specially since 1^2+2^2+...+(n-14)^2 eventually surpasses n.

Comment: @Mathematics For $k=n-14$ the sum can include at most one $3^2$, and at most five $2^2$. The rest must be $1^2$.

Comment: I can't see it. Oh, can, I read must.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, why can't we have more than one $3^2$, and more than five $2^2$?

Comment: I can't really see how you derived that, can you give some explanation?

Comment: If $n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-14}n_i^2$ and $n_i\geq4$ then
$$n\geq4^2+(n-15)\cdot1^2=n+1.$$

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa67/aa6745.pdf

Comment: Bateman-Hildebrand-Purdy Theorem 2: if $s \geq 5$  and $n \geq (n-1)^5, \; \; $  then $n$ is expressible as the sum of $s$ distinct nonzero squares. The tables at the end of the article suggest that, if $s \geq 7$  and $n \geq s^3, \; \; $  then $n$ is expressible as the sum of $s$ distinct nonzero squares.  Not sure whether they prove that

Comment: @WillJagy I think there is a typo somewhere? For a positive integer $n$ the condition $n\geq(n-1)^5$ is equivalent to $n=1,2$. Did you mean $n\geq(s-1)^5$?

Comment: Servaes, yes $n \geq (s-1)^5.$ I just copied from the Bateman Hildebrand paper, link above. I'm not sure what the question above actually wants....